# Trying to separate the NSURLConnection function into another class but get error on delegation

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, nsurlconnection

I want to create a MVC iphone app , a part of my app task is to get data from internet and I want to separate that part to a Model and here is what I've written

```
//Connection.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Connection : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableData * rawData;
    BOOL ready;
}


-(id) initWithData;
-(BOOL) isDataReady;

@end


//Connection.m
#import "Connection.h"


@implementation Connection

-(id) initWithData
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        ready = NO;
        rawData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
        NSURLRequest * request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[request delegate:self]];

        [rawData setLength:0];

        return self;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
//I have implemented the connectiondidRecievedData and connectionDidFinishLoading also they are empty
```

but when I want to call this class from my controller I'll get error

```
Connection * cn = [[Connection alloc] initWithData];
```

and the error is

> 2012-01-13 15:26:59.453 TestApp[20105:207] -[NSURLRequest delegate:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1f520 2012-01-13
>   15:26:59.455 TestApp[20105:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURLRequest
>   delegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1f520'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dd05a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00f24313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00dd20bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00d41966 __*forwarding*** + 966
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d41522
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50    5   TestApp                             0x0000257c -[Connection initWithData] + 339     6   TestApp
>   0x000020c3 -[TestAppViewController doTestB] + 122     7   UIKit
>   0x002c04fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119    8
>   UIKit                               0x00350799 -[UIControl
>   sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     9   UIKit
>   0x00352c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   527   10  UIKit                               0x003517d8 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458    11  UIKit
>   0x002e4ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567    12  UIKit
>   0x002c5c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447  13  UIKit
>   0x002caf2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576   14  GraphicsServices
>   0x01728992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550     15  CoreFoundation
>   0x00db1944 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d11cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215   17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0ef83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979     18  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d0e840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208     19  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d0e761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    20  GraphicsServices
>   0x017271c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  21  GraphicsServices
>   0x01727289 GSEventRun + 115   22  UIKit
>   0x002cec93 UIApplicationMain + 1160   23  TestApp
>   0x00001e04 main + 102     24  TestApp
>   0x00001d95 start + 53 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException'

how can I separate the NSURLConnection to another class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an error in your code here:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[request delegate:self]];
```

That should read:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```